# Close a popup inside a map by clicking outside the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I have a map something like Google maps and when I click on points on the map, a popup will open that is dynamically generated by the map plugin I use. I want to close the popup when I click outside the map.The code I wrote hides the whole map, but I want that popup to close.the popup that is created dynamically has this id `MapPopupId` .How can I solve this?

```
      const MapView = () => {    
      const { ref, isVisible } = useClickOutside()

         {isVisible && (
          <div className="mapView" ref={ref}>
            <Map/>
         </div>
           )}
         }
```

and my custom hook is

```
export default function useClickOutside () {
const ref = useRef(null)
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, false)
return () => {
  document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, false)
}
 }, [])

 const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
 if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
  setIsVisible(false)
 }
 }

return { ref, isVisible }
}
```

Comment: it's working as expected because you're not rendering the `popup` conditionally, since you don't have the control on the `Map` plugin, you can write code to remove the element from document but I suggest to have a better understanding of the internals of the library before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the popup is created dynamically and I do not have access to it to set ref. So, I have to solve this problem in this way

```
const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
  if (document.getElementById('MapPopupId')) {
    document.getElementById('MapPopupId').style.display = 'none'
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the popup element in your custom hook:

```
export default function useClickOutside() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const popupRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  // ...
}
```

Update the JSX code to include the popup with the specified ID:
const MapView = () => {
const { mapRef, popupRef, isVisible } = useClickOutside();

```
  return (
    <>
      {isVisible && (
        <div className="mapView" ref={mapRef}>
          <Map />
          <div className="popup" id="MapPopupId" ref={popupRef}>
            {/* Popup content */}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Modify the handleClickOutside function to check if the clicked element is not within the map or the popup:

```
const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
  if (
    mapRef.current &&
    !mapRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
    popupRef.current &&
    !popupRef.current.contains(event.target)
  ) {
    setIsVisible(false);
  }
};
```

With these changes, the popup with the ID "MapPopupId" will remain open when clicking inside it but will close when clicking outside the map or the popup itself.

Comment: thank u for your solution but the popup is created dynamically and I should not create it. so I do not have control on it to set ref